# Chaining multiple "transitionend" EventListener's

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events, addeventlistener

I want to chain multiple images using a EventListenner with "transitionend", let's say for example I have a game of rock-paper-scissors, and every time I click one of the buttons to play, I want the image to rotate from rock, to paper, and finally to scissors, waiting each time for the end of the transition before swapping image again, to simulate the game interaction in real life.  I've managed to chain one of the transitions but I'm stuck on the logic of how I would do it for multiple consecutive `"transitionend"` events

```js
let images = ['https://adiihd.github.io/rock-paper-scissors-game/img/rock.png', 'https://adiihd.github.io/rock-paper-scissors-game/img/paper.png', 'https://adiihd.github.io/rock-paper-scissors-game/img/scissors.png'];

const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

// we use the .forEach method to iterate through each button
buttons.forEach((button) => {
  // and for each one we add a 'click' listener
  button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    let userImg = document.querySelector("#userimg");
    userImg.classList.add("playing");
    userImg.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
      userImg.classList.remove("playing");
      userImg.setAttribute('src', images[1]);
    });
    userImg.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
      userImg.classList.remove("playing");
      userImg.setAttribute('src', images[2]);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#userimg {
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  width: 200px;
}

.playing {
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}
```

```html
<img id="userimg" src="https://adiihd.github.io/rock-paper-scissors-game/img/rock.png">
<br>
<button id="Rock">Rock</button>
<button id="Paper">Paper</button>
<button id="Scissors">Scissors</button>
```

Comment: I would consider using `setTimeout` instead of CSS classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Waiting for transitionend will probably cause more problems than it's worth. I'm not sure about your browser compatibility requirements, but if you can use animations I recommend using them:

```js
let images = ['https://adiihd.github.io/rock-paper-scissors-game/img/rock.png', 'https://adiihd.github.io/rock-paper-scissors-game/img/paper.png', 'https://adiihd.github.io/rock-paper-scissors-game/img/scissors.png'];

const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

// we use the .forEach method to iterate through each button
buttons.forEach((button) => {
  // and for each one we add a 'click' listener
  button.addEventListener('click', async (e) => {
    let userImg = document.querySelector(".userimg");
    userImg.classList.remove("userimg-animation");
    
    // Force a reflow, see https://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/
    userImg.offsetWidth;
    
    userImg.classList.add("userimg-animation");
    userImg.setAttribute("choice", button.id.toLowerCase());
  });
});
```

```css
.imageHolder {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.spacerimg {
  opacity: 0;
}

.userimg-animation {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  animation-name: rockpaperscissors;
  animation-duration: 1.2s;
}

.userimg {
  background-repeat: no-repeat!important;
}

.userimg[choice="rock"] {
  background: url(https://adiihd.github.io/rock-paper-scissors-game/img/rock.png);
}
.userimg[choice="paper"] {
  background: url(https://adiihd.github.io/rock-paper-scissors-game/img/paper.png);
}
.userimg[choice="scissors"] {
  background: url(https://adiihd.github.io/rock-paper-scissors-game/img/scissors.png);
}

@keyframes rockpaperscissors {
  0% {
    background: url(https://adiihd.github.io/rock-paper-scissors-game/img/rock.png);
  }
  33.2% {
    background: url(https://adiihd.github.io/rock-paper-scissors-game/img/rock.png);
  }
  33.3% {
    background: url(https://adiihd.github.io/rock-paper-scissors-game/img/paper.png);
  }
  66.5% {
    background: url(https://adiihd.github.io/rock-paper-scissors-game/img/paper.png);
  }
  66.6% {
    background: url(https://adiihd.github.io/rock-paper-scissors-game/img/scissors.png);
  }
  99.9% {
    background: url(https://adiihd.github.io/rock-paper-scissors-game/img/scissors.png);
  }
  100% {
    background: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="imageHolder">
  <div class="userimg"></div>
  <img class="spacerimg" src="https://adiihd.github.io/rock-paper-scissors-game/img/rock.png">
</div>
<br>
<button id="Rock">Rock</button>
<button id="Paper">Paper</button>
<button id="Scissors">Scissors</button>
```

NOTE: I had to write extra keyframes in order to prevent animations between backgrounds (they fade between each other). However you may want animations, so if you remove every odd keyframe you will have less CSS and they will animate between each other.